# Mysqli query with form is not working - everything looks correct, no syntax

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have checked and searched but nothing fits my problem, where nothing actually looks faulty. Maybe im just tired, maybe im just bad, here's the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add_room'])){
    include('php/connect.php');
    $desc = $_POST['room_description'];
    $cleaned = 1;
    $cleaner = "admin";
    $date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO rooms (Desc, Cleaned, Cleaner, Time) VALUES ('$desc', '$cleaned', '$cleaner', '$date')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

};
?>

<div id="slide-admin" style="display: none;" class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 sd-adm">
<div class="btn btn-default add_room-btn">Nytt rum?</div>    
<div class="add_room" style="display:none;">
    <form class="add_room-form" method="post">
        <input name="room_description" class="room_description" placeholder="Rumsinfo"></input>
        <input name="add_room" value="Lägg till rum" type="submit" class="btn btn-success add_room-btn-send"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

*The hardcoded values are just for testing purposes, the connect.php is tested and working properly, and yes i have sql injection holes, just testing.

Comment: Beside error reporting issue, you have to use prepared statement for your query

Comment: What i just wrote, i am aware of that

Comment: Reserved Words. Again and again.